# Google App Engine is slower in the cloud than on my laptop

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying out Google App Engine with PHP, the script executes a lot slower in the cloud than it does on my laptop.

The cloud execution time averages at about 35 seconds, whilst my macbook air runs the same script locally on App Engine in about 6 seconds.

What am I missing to boost performance in the cloud?

**Setup**

Fontend instance class: F4_1G (2400mhz, 1024mb)

app.yaml warmup instances configuration:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

**Script for testing performance**

```
<?php
$starttime = microtime(true);

echo "Starts performing.<br>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
    $test = md5($i);
    $test2 = hash("sha512", $test);
    $newstring = $test . "-" . $test2;
    $test3 = hash("sha512", $newstring);
    $newstring2 = $newstring . "-" . $test3;
    $test4 = hash("sha512", $newstring2);
}
echo "Done performing.";
echo "<hr>";

$diff = microtime(true) - $starttime;

$sec = intval($diff);
$micro = $diff - $sec;

$final = strftime('%T', mktime(0, 0, $sec)) . str_replace('0.', '.', sprintf('%.3f', $micro));
echo "Execution time total: $final";
```

Comment: Any results available?

Comment: Laptop: Execution time total: 00:00:05.658
Cloud: Execution time total: 00:00:36.902

Comment: GAE is more about scalability then raw performance. Instances take time to create also, does your timing include or exclude that time?

Comment: I'm assuming it includes it, but I thought that by adding the warmup, the instance would be always on?

Comment: +1 at Paul. Make sure that your instance was running before running that test. If instead it's booting up, then it's normal it takes time. You could also set up your default module's configuration to at least 1 idle to make sure that this isn't the case: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Instance_uptime

Comment: @Publicus, no, the inboud services will enable warmup requests. Take a look at this doc for more details: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Comment: I see two instances running, and it makes sense, because the setup is set to allow for 1 idle instance (and warmup is enabled). So one for handling the request, and one idle which is ready.

Comment: @Publicus  Did you try using a stopwatch and checking?  Using your script, there seems to be a discrepancy between showed time and real time on devserver.  Not saying devserver is slower than GAE, but running devserver shows 7-8 seconds here, while timing it with a stopwatch gives 20-22 seconds (about the same speed as GAE)

Comment: @Julldar I checked now with a stopwatch, and the result from the stopwatch and from the script is the same. (This time 5 seconds for the laptop, and 17 seconds for AppEngine). I understand that it's made for scalability and not for raw performance, but I was a bit suprised to see such a big difference.

Comment: @Publicus  good.  For some reason I see a BIG difference with a stopwatch, but it still doesn't make the devserver slower.  It just makes a smaller, less scary difference (22-20 is better than 17-5 :P).  Might be interesting to run the same test, but using the GAE APIs (I'm convinced if you hit the datastore instead of pure computing power as your script is doing, production server will be faster)